# Proper way to send connection string from .Net core app to a class library

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture

I have a .Net core MVC application and a class library names UIServiceLayer. UIServicelayer has following classes:

1. public class Page.
2. internal class Widget.
3. internal class WidgetType.
4. --- some more internal classes related to UI objects.
5. internal class Data.

In UIServicelayer, only the Page class is public, and it is the sole interaction point with the UIServicelayer.

I have connection string stored in my .Net Core MVC application's appsettings.json file, which I need to pass to Data.cs class, so that it can establish connection with DB.

The problem is that I do not want to pass connection string through the Page.cs class, because Page class should not be concerned with anything other than UI page and widgets and stuff, and I also don't want to mark Data class as public, because I don't want my .Net Core app to interact with Data class directly.

Can anyone suggest me how to pass connection string to Data class from my .Net Core app?

Comment: What is the relationship between Page class in .net core app and class librabry? If you get the data in Data.cs, will it continue to return to the .net core app?

Comment: @Karney. .Net core app can ask the Page class things like "Give me the list of all widgets on this particular form" or "Give me the child widgets of this particular widget" etc... The page class will then prepare appropriate SQL queries and send them to Data class. It is Data class' responsibility to create connection with DB and execute the queries sent by Page class. The Data class will send the results to Page class, which will return format and return the results to .Net Core app. Since ADO .Net code is in Data class, that is why I need to send DB connection information to Data class.

Comment: @Karney. Page class is responsible for generating the logic (SQL statements) that will fetch us required data. Data class is responsible to create connection with DB and execute these SQL queries.

Comment: Can you add a public interface (something like `IDatabaseConfiguration`) to your project? You can add a property on this containing your connection string. Then you an use DI (dependency injection) and resolve it. Your `UIServiceLayer` only knows about the interface and your MVC application is responsible to fill in the connection string value. Would that be an option?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Thanks.